# css style in the ext js combo box

Tags: css, extjs

My code:

```
{
  border: 1,
  bodyStyle: 'margin:0 0 0 140px;',
  style: {
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderStyle: 'solid', //margin:'0 0 0 140' //margin-left: '140px' }, width: 140, name: 'comp', id:'compId', triggerAction: 'all', mode: 'local', store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields: ['myId', 'displayText'],
    data: [
      [1, 'item1'],
      [2, 'item2']
    ]
  }), displayField: 'displayText', xtype: 'combo',
},
```

here in ext js 2.3 bodyStyle is not getting appended to the combobox.Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be what you need.

```
{
    xtype: 'combo'
    style : 'margin-left: 140px; border: solid black 1px;',
    name: 'comp', 
    id:'compId', 
    triggerAction: 'all', 
    mode: 'local', 
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['myId', 'displayText'],
        data: [
          [1, 'item1'],
          [2, 'item2']
        ]
      }), 
    displayField: 'displayText',
    valueField : 'myId'

}
```

Note there is no bodyStyle config option according to the docs - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox

I removed the width option as with the margin-left style attribute (also 140px) I thought you may end up with something odd looking.

Comment: This is not helping out in my case. I have a textfield and inline to it im placing this combo box.

Comment: i have {xtype:'textfield',value:"comboValue",width:140px} and placed a combox box next to it using the above code so i wanted to apply margin-style to the bodyStyle and not to the inner element. bodyStyle will apply style to the entire combobox and style element will apply to its inner element i.e. text.

Comment: Can you post your whole code so I can see exactly what you are trying to achieve with the layout of your fields? It sounds like you are trying to place a texfield inside a combo box as you say are placing it inline, which I don't think you can do with ExtJS

Comment: please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409834/combo-box-placed-next-to-the-textfield-using-extjs) . i have posted my question with code

Answer (score 0):

combo.js :

```
{xtype:'combobox', cls:'combo'}
```

combo.css:

```
.combo .x-boundlist-selected {
  background: #757575;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #757575, #474747);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #757575, #474747);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #757575, #474747);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #757575, #474747);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #757575, #474747);
  border: solid #4e4e4e 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.combo .x-boundlist-item {
  background: #757575;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #757575, #474747);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #757575, #474747);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #757575, #474747);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #757575, #474747);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #757575, #474747);
  border: solid #4e4e4e 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the code that used bodyStyle atribute in 2.3 version
this may help you.

```
this.itemCombo= new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                name : "combooo",
                fieldLabel : "Status",
                displayField : 'combo',
                valueField : 'id',
                mode : 'local',
                triggerAction : 'all',
                hiddenName : "comboo",
                editable : false,
                width : 100,
                store : this.store,
                value : "0"
            });


    this.frmPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                bodyStyle : "padding:10px",
                border : true,
                autoScroll : true,
                layout : "table",
                layoutConfig : {
                    columns : 1,
                    style : "vertical-align:top"
                },
                items : [{
                    bodyStyle : "padding-right:10px",
                    xtype : "panel",
                    layout : "form",
                    border : false,
                    labelWidth : 110,
                    colspan : 2,
                    items : [this.item1,this.itemCombo]
                }]
            });
```